# ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable when running from Visual Studio

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

I recently configured our Azure App Service and Azure SQL Server to use managed identity access. The App Service has System assigned managed identity and has the correct assigned role as Owner for the SQL database. When I publish my code to the app service it works just fine and is able to access the database.

My issue is that I cannot connect to the database through my app when running it locally through Visual Studio. My Azure account is set as the Azure Active Directory admin on SQL Server and I'm able to open up the connection and run queries through Azure Data Studio when I'm signed in.

I'm using the same account through Visual Studio, even unlinked and relinked it under the Tools -> Options -> Azure Service Authentication / Account Selection. But when I try and run the app locally I get the error `ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Multiple attempts failed to obtain a token from the managed identity endpoint.`
The error doesn't give me much to work with because I'm not sure how to see the full view of what is being tried in order to authenticate. I'm not using any code on my end to obtain an access token since I'm just letting the Microsoft SQLClient obtain it for me through my connection string.

Here is the full stacktrace of the error, anything that can point me in the right direction would be appreciated. My guess is it has something to do with Visual Studios probably needing to be allowed to get an access token on my behalf, but I figured since I'm signed into my azure account it might not matter.

```
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetSingle[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)

Azure.RequestFailedException: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. (169.254.169.254:80)
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network. (169.254.169.254:80)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10051): A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpClientTransport.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineTransportPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RequestActivityPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.ResponseBodyPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RedirectPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)

   at Azure.Identity.ImdsManagedIdentitySource.<AuthenticateAsync>d__15.MoveNext()
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityClient.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityClient.<AppTokenProviderImpl>d__18.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialRequest.<SendTokenRequestToProviderAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialRequest.<FetchNewAccessTokenAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialRequest.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.<RunAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.ConfidentialClientExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at Azure.Identity.AbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilderExtensions.<ExecuteAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext()
   at Azure.Identity.MsalConfidentialClient.<AcquireTokenForClientCoreAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
   at Azure.Identity.MsalConfidentialClient.<AcquireTokenForClientAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityClient.<AuthenticateAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.<GetTokenImplAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
   at 


Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, String additionalMessage)
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.<GetTokenImplAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.<GetTokenAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationProvider.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.<>c__DisplayClass147_1.<<GetFedAuthToken>b__1>d.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.GetFedAuthToken(SqlFedAuthInfo fedAuthInfo)
```

Relevant connection DbContext information. Currently using version 7.0.3 of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore for the DbContext class

```
    public class DbEntities: DbContext
    {
        public DbEntities() : base() { }
        //All DbSet<...> classes here
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DB_CONNECTION_STRING"));
        }
    }
```

Relevant AppSettings JSON file

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DB_CONNECTION_STRING": "Server=tcp:MY-SERVER.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=development;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication=\"Active Directory Managed Identity\";"
  },
}
```

Comment: So what do you want to achieve? Want to connect azure sql to your app locally or want to authenticate your app? In  addition, it also need to know what you are trying to implement and your configuration beside your stack trace.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Both I suppose, I want the behavior to be identical as if the app were deployed. So right now I just need to be able to connect to the database through the local app. This is an existing application that I'm updating to work with managed identity. Currently using ```DbContext``` provided through version  7.0.3 of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore package. I added the relevant connection information in my original post

Comment: Try signing in to the account you want using Azure CLI (`az login`). Though I'm not sure it will work for this exact connection string. You might need `Active Directory Default` for authentication.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Essentially I'm trying to answer the question why am I able to open the database connection through Azure Data Studio but not through my local application in Visual Studios when my microsoft account is connected to both.

Comment: @AlexAIT signing in with azure cli made no difference. Still getting the same errors. Will try ```Active Directory Default``` and see if that changes anything

Comment: @AlexAIT Ok, changing the connection string to use ```Active Directory Default``` instead of ```Active Directory Managed Identity``` seems to let it work on both ```localhost``` and on my azure app service. Not sure why....but I'll take it

Comment: Awesome, I posted it as an answer including some additional information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16

By using `Authentication=\"Active Directory Managed Identity\"` you will tell your application to use **only** managed identity authentication. This can only be used if you are actually running as an Azure resource. You cannot use Managed Identity authentication with your personal account.

By using `Active Directory Default` as the value, the system will try multiple variants:

> Authenticate with an Azure AD identity by using password-less and non-interactive mechanisms including Managed Identities, Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio, Azure CLI, etc.